# Best way to implement a two byte integer in C?

Tags: c

I am working on a project where conserving space is a consideration. I want to create an array of two-byte integers. What is the best way to implement this type? Right now I am considering using a struct and letting functions do the conversions when I need to read or manipulate the value:

```
typedef struct {
    char a;
    char b;
} int_16;
```

... but I wonder if there is a more efficient or standard way to approach a problem like this.

Comment: short?.................int16_t?

Comment: Or use `int16_t`? In a `struct`, you can use a 16 bit bit-field.

Comment: this don't exist in C, `short` will generally have two bytes, but nothing prevent it to be more. `int16_t` is only two byte if `CHAR_BIT` is `8`, this is true for 99% of actual system.

Comment: `struct` isn't a good idea. You can't write `int_16 t = 123;`.